# Disable a button if either of the two TextBoxes are empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two text boxes and one button. If either of the boxes is empty or white space, the button should be disabled.

```
<TextBox Name="firstNameTxtBox" />
<TextBox Name="lastNameTxtBox" />

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Save}"  Style="{StaticResource saveButtonEnabler}" />
```

And the `saveButtonEnabler` resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:IsButtonEnabledConverter x:Key="isButtonEnabledConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="saveButtonEnabler" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Converter={StaticResource isButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="???" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=lastNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Converter={StaticResource isButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="???" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Converter gets called appropriately, but I have not idea how to set the result to the `Value` of the `Condition`.

```
public class IsButtonEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == 0 ? false : true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: your `Value="???"` should be `Value="true"` because if both Textboxes contain a string aka `Text.Length>0` you want to Enabled your Button

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually you need to use 2 triggers to set IsEnabled to false. Your current implementation is AND and what you want is OR.

```
<TextBox x:Name="firstNameTxtBox"/>
<TextBox x:Name="lastNameTxtBox"/>
<Button Content="Save">
  <Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
             </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=lastNameTxtBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

If you however want to use the valueconverter approach all you need to do is use 'True' as the Value in your trigger bindings as such

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Converter={StaticResource isButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="True" />
<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=lastNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Converter={StaticResource isButtonEnabledConverter}}" Value="True" />
```

Comment: his current "AND" implementation isn't the problem, because he is going to set IsEnabled=true which is just the same like you do with your IsEnabled=false

Comment: Yes, if OP wants to use valueconverter, he could do with AND, but it is way easier to not use valueconverter and use OR kind of trigger setup.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `IsEnabled` property of the button if you have one `TextBox`:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Save}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

For both `TextBoxes` try this (*You don't need to use converter*):

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=lastNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

Your complete code would be:

```
<TextBox Name="firstNameTxtBox" />
<TextBox Name="lastNameTxtBox" />

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Save}" >
      <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <MultiDataTrigger>
                      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                         <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=firstNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                         <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=lastNameTxtBox, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                 </MultiDataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: yes, that works. However, I need to check the content of both firstNameTxtBox and lastNameTxtBox.

Comment: @Mefhisto1 you could use your MultiDataTrigger in combination with this answer

Comment: This is case "if both textboxes are empty", OP wants "if either of textboxes is empty"

Comment: @gts13 you can use OP's code but change the Value="0" to Value="True"

Comment: In one textbox example, How that Text.Length which is a int is translated to boolean?

Answer (score 2):

This will work without converter:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="Foo1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Foo2"/>
    <Button Content="Push me">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=Foo1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=Foo2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your converter is returning a boolean, so you definitely  have to set your value to True.

But I would change my converter a little bit:
Instead of:

```
return (int)value == 0 ? false:true;
```

I would do:

```
return ((int)value) !=0;
```